# Merging multiple tables without duplicating IDs using SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on search interface and my problem is that the ids are all duplicating making the searched word go wrong. How can I merge multiple tables without duplicating ids?

Example:

Table1

```
_id   ques   long
1     hello  tung
2     ask    bung
3     bun    hot
```

Table2

```
_id   ques   long
1     hind   sling
2     scent  pong
3     brun   jit
```

Table3

```
_id   ques   long
1     pont   rave
2     sue    lace
3     brun   bass
```

The output should be like this

```
_id   ques   long
1     hello  tung
2     ask    bung
3     bun    hot
4     hind   sling
5     scent  pong
6     brun   jit
7     pont   rave
8     sue    lace
9     brun   bass
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT ques, long FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT ques, long FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT ques, long FROM Table3
```

The `_id` **can't be changed** (it will always return 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3).
So, I didn't include it in the query.

You might use the row position, if you want to show a consecutive number.
You'd probably end up creating a [View](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_views.htm) using the suggested query.

Then query the View using something like

```
SELECT rowID AS _id, ques, long FROM myView
```

This way, the _id returning from the View will be in the desired sequence: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

Comment: So there are no way to have it in 1,2,3,4,5,6....? In MySql there is so called row_number(), is there any equivalent of row_number() in SQLite?

Comment: Yes, it's called `rowID`. But you need a query like `SELECT rowID AS _id, * FROM ...`.

Comment: If I use rowID, is it possible to make my IDs consecutively or not? If yes, how?

Comment: You probably have to make a **View** using the suggested query. Then query the View using something like `SELECT rowID AS _id, * FROM myView`.